# How to get the position of same Values in multiple Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have several numpy arrays with sensordata. I need the position for every array with the same time so i can assign them together.

The arrays look something like this but with alot more values (around 1000 and i have 21 arrays):

x1 = [0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 10]

x2 = [1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

x3 = [0, 1, 3, 7, 9, 10]

xn = [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

Now i need to know the position of every array IF the value is existing in all of them. In the Example that would be the position in all 21 arrays for the timestamp 1, 3, 7 and 10.

As always iam apprechiating every help!

Comment: You're better off using a set for something like that

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather primitive approach (illustrated for 3 arrays, but easily extendable to an arbitrary number of arrays):

```
x1 = np.array([0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 10])
x2 = np.array([1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
x3 = np.array([0, 1, 3, 7, 9, 10])

arrays = [x1, x2, x3]
```

Fetch the values that are in all arrays (pack array values in sets and intersect over all sets):

```
from functools import reduce

values = reduce(set.intersection, arrays, set(x1))
```

Result:

```
{1, 10, 3, 7}
```

Then select for each of those values the corresponding indices from the arrays and pack them into a dictionary:

```
indices = {value: tuple(i
                        for array in arrays
                        for i in range(len(array))
                        if array[i] == value)
           for value in values}
```

Result:

```
{1: (1, 0, 1), 10: (5, 5, 5), 3: (2, 1, 2), 7: (4, 2, 3)}
```

But: This only works if the values in the arrays are unique!

Comment: The reduce function can be `set.intersect`, no lambda necessary

Comment: I suspect the result would be more useful as a numpy array

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good point, always avoid lambdas if possible. Will update.

Comment: They are unique! Thanks alot i will try it right after i hit home

Comment: There is a tendency, especially among new users, to keep the old version of everything around. There's no need to do that. It's better to keep the most concise version around, and rely on the revision history to do its job. That way your answer will be the best it can be, without any unnecessary cruft.

Comment: @Timus That solved my problem! Thank you!